# Play 360° video in Cordova app on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, video, 360-panorama

I'm trying to include a 360° video (not 3D) in a Cordova app.
I know Youtube can play them but it needs to be available offline.

Here are my requirements:

- Works on Android and iOS
- Works with and without Google Cardboard (optionally other VR headsets)
- Can play a 4K (4096 x 2048 px) video without too much lag
- Available offline
- Available in English, French and German. Or easily translatable.

I tried out [Google Web VR View](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview) but it doesn't work on iOS and doesn't display properly on Android.

I'd also be willing to pay to have a Cordova native plugin implemented (probably using the native Google VR View SDK) but I'm uncertain why that doesn't exist yet.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a web based VR library? Or do you know of a Cordova plugin or a reason why creating a Cordova plugin could be difficult?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. In the end I went with a link to YouTube. Because of this it only works when you have an internet connection and the YouTube app installed since YouTube doesn't support VR on the mobile website.

Comment: Ouch.  JW Player has an SDK for native android/iOS apps.  But who knows if it would even be compatible with Cordova, plus then you'd have to figure a way to plug it in anyway.  Disappointing.